# What is the purpose of elementClass parameter in ServerResponse.BodyBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

There's a simple model class, which is supposed to be used for response body serialization:

```
public class MyModel{
  public String name;
}
```

Using it in an arbitrary Spring 5 handler function:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getSometing(ServerRequest request) {
  MyModel model = new MyModel();
  model.name = "abc";

  return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(model), %anyClass%);
}
```

I tried to substitute for `%anyClass%` different classes: `Object`, `String`, `MyModel`, `RuntimeException` - and the result is always the same. Every time the model instance had been serialized to a json `{"name" : "abc"}`.

It also works for more complex models with nested objects and arrays.

Could you comment, what is the purpose of the second parameter (`elementClass` ) if it does not affect the result? Why cannot we use `Object.class` always?

Comment: I expect that all parameters of `body()` method affect its result. If there's no difference when I offer `MyModel.class` or `Object.class`, what is the purpose of even requiring this parameter?

Comment: Just looked at the source code, it's eventually used in `org\springframework\http\codec\json\AbstractJackson2Encoder.java`, so if you had a custom serializer for your class you could pass the class in that you want it serialized as.

Comment: Actually something weird happens, and it's always set `class.java.lang.object`...

Comment: @123 Try `URI.class` as a placeholder for `%anyClass%` to see a different encoding behavior.

Comment: Yeah ignore my second comment, that was because of something else

Answer (score -1):

Its not anyclass, its generally the type of class you want to publish/produce. In your case Its can be the MyModel.class, the one you are sending in the response.

If you read the spring documentation, it will make more sense to you.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerResponse.BodyBuilder.html

You can update the last line of your code :
ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(model), MyModel.class)

Comment: I suppose, you've missed the point. Yes, what is written in documentation is the expected behavior. Unexpectedly, I've found out that even when I violate contract of the method, serialization works fine. Doesn't it surprise you?